# Has the CIL(Common Intermediate Language) changed for .Net 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, bytecode, command-line-interface

I know that until 3.5, .Net uses the byte code defined in .Net 2.0.

I am wondering whether the new 4.0 byte code changes or not. Thanks!

As the latest ECMA standard file is still the 2006 one, I suspect the 4.0 does not change the byte code.

**EDIT:** I did a little search on the web and found that CIL are .Net bytecode are different things. My understanding is that CIL to .Net bytecode is as asm to machine code. So my question still holds, does the CIL/Bytecode change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between CLR 2.0 and CLR 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626368/difference-between-clr-2-0-and-clr-4-0)

Comment: Not really. That question is about changes to the CLR, not the CIL. In fact, only one of the answers even mentions CIL, and only to state that the answerer doesn't "believe" there are new instructions.

Comment: All that the ECMA standard version means is that Microsoft hasn't submitted a new one. The ECMA standard version for C# hasn't changed either since C# 2.0, but we all know that there were significant changes in C# 3.0 (lambdas, local variable type inference, anonymous structural types, LINQ query comprehensions) and C# 4.0 (generic co- and contravariance, `dynamic`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the CLR has been changed:

From the [.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx) page:

> .NET Framework version 4: Includes a new version of the CLR, expanded base class libraries, and new features such as the Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF), dynamic language runtime (DLR), and code contracts.

Concerning changes to the CIL (MSIL), the closest I came is that there are no changes to the `System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes` class, which should describe all available opcodes. I verified this by comparing the 4.0 documentation version with the 3.5 documentation version.

Comment: You're totally correct. I find it's very difficult to find concrete information on this, other than the `OpCodes` class; expanded answer with this information.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.Now there is CLR version 4.0.This is Latest version is 4.6.

Please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bs2ecf4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.